# How do I add to an existing Rar Archive with a Batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, archive, rar

I have just got a network cloud (NAS) drive. I am backing up files and so on but like to use batch files for quick and easy backups locally.

I am creating several archives (.rar) to include several different folders - i.e. "e:\folder1", "e:\folder2", etc. including all subfolders and files.

Then, once they are set up I want to run a batch file to scan the relevant folders and add to each related archive any files that have subsequently been copied to the folders.

e.g. Folders:

```
e:\digitalimages\2014\photos (and subfolders) - into archive "2014 Photos"
e:\digitalimages\2014\videos (and subfolders) - into archive "2014 Videos"
e:\digitalimages\2015\photos (and subfolders) - into archive "2015 Photos"
e:\digitalimages\2015\photos (and subfolders) - into archive "2015 Photos"
```

run a batch file to scan the e:\digitalimages\2014\photos folder and add any newer files to archive "2014 Photos".

Does this make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: You know, the Windows Backup is really quite good.  It does what you're describing already, just not with rar files.  If you can get past that minor detail, the ability to right-click a folder and restore previous versions by date is slick.  You're asking for help building a moped when you've already got a Triumph sitting in your driveway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WinRAR's `a` command to simply add files to an existing archive.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r "2014 Photos.rar" E:\digitalimages\2014\photos
```

Comment: Thanks SomethingDark. 

Do I read it correctly? I simply use the same command for for 'making' an archive to add to an 'existing' archive? 

Stuart

Comment: Yep! That's all there is to it!